# lldb: Breakpoint on exceptions (equivalent of gdb's catch throw)

Tags: debugging, llvm, lldb

I am trying to use lldb for c++ debugging and I want to halt if an exception is thrown, like gdb's `catch throw`, and I cannot find an equivalent in the lldb documentation.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In Xcode, you can set an Exception breakpoint (View > Navigators > Show Breakpoint Navigator, hit the + button in the bottom of the breakpoint list window to add a new breakpoint).

If you're using command line lldb, put a breakpoint on `__cxa_throw` for C++ exception throws, `objc_exception_throw` for Objective-C exception throws.

For all c++ exceptions: `break set -E C++`.

Comment: for all c++ exceptions: break set -E c++

Comment: ah, I missed the -E option to breakpoint set!  Thanks for noting it.

Comment: The '-F' and '-E' variants weren't working for me, but 'breakpoint -n __cxa_throw' did work (for all exceptions), as well as 'breakpoint -n <exception-name>' (for specific exceptions).

Comment: "-E objc" also works if you want Objective-C exceptions.

Comment: `break set -E c++` didn't work for me (perhaps because I'm using real GNU g++ instead of Apple's clang++?), but `break set -n __cxa_throw` did. @AnthonyHall's comment is lacking `set`.

Answer (score 83):

Use `breakpoint set -E c++` to break on all exceptions and `breakpoint set -F std::range_error`  to break on a specific exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think `breakpoint set -w <boolean>` is the correct answer, you can use `help breakpoint set` to see the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter

```
breakpoint set -E c++
```

into LLDB to do this.

But if you want to configure LLDB to always do this, open `~/.lldbinit` and put the same line into that file.